# Highstock: Multiple series in one chart

Tags: highcharts

The example on the demo page shows the prices and the volumes on 2 charts (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume).

Is it possible to render them in one chart only?

It seems that solution from [How to display the prices and the volumes on a candlesticks chart with Highstock Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578552/how-to-display-the-prices-and-the-volumes-on-a-candlesticks-chart-with-highstock)
is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to render both series on one graph: http://jsfiddle.net/34pyk8jf/

Comment: Thank you!! Is it possible to adding macd in the second panel of highcharts? (i dont ask you to do it :), i mean is it possible)

Comment: It should be possible to add another axis for your indicator. Example (with rsi series): http://jsfiddle.net/34pyk8jf/1/

Comment: I added MACD, and added animation to chart (with 600 ms step). http://jsfiddle.net/Lgvk636x/27/    But I see strange behaviour. It works only if 'volume' serie go after 'candlestick' in series array. P.S. is it possible to improve performance of animation?

Comment: I fixed first problem. But question about performance still actual. I must use another library, maybee d3.js?

Comment: unfortunately, I am not able to recreate your performance issues: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgvk636x/31/ hovewer, I think that you should be able to use boost.js for improving performance of your charts: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost/